# CSS padding and font issue

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with font settings and padding in CSS, I am a visual person and I bet you are one too, so here's my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSsTI.png if you can solve it I will give you an upvote :O

Comment: Your existing code would be extremely helpful, if not required.

Comment: Indeed, the code would make it easy to fix :)
Because i'm curious about how you position the buttons.

Comment: like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2kYuG/1/ but still, to know it's the right solution, i need to see your code.

Comment: How is it a font issue?  If the boxes need resized you can try specifying the size in em instead of pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is the `line-height` property.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/J2g6y/

Comment: I tried it and it works but depending whether I zoom in or out of the browser it stops working.

Comment: Ah ok, well I was going by the question / image supplied... not by mind reading what the **actual** problem is... Just out of interest, @Alec, how exactly did you get `line-height` from the question and image?

Comment: @user472755: In reply to your edit, try using my solution - but replace the absolute divs with an absolute `ul`, with `bottom: 0px; left: 10%;` and several `li` tags with `float: left`. Dont use `position: absolute` on the `li` tags.

Comment: @user472755, my Fiddle example scales just fine here. Like everyone else said: we can't help you properly if you don't post your code.

Comment: I followed your model and it does work, turns out in your example of for #nav in mine I had padding:1em; added to it, and that screwed things up, I find that rather unfortunate but that's Okay I guess if I add manually padding:1em; to each object that needed spacing on, I will I get the result I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I would let the header grow to have it's bottom pushed down by the growing buttons, but if I wanted to just adjust based on the text, I'd move the text up 1em (which is it's own height)

you can play with it [here](http://craigslist.fatherstorm.com/stackoverflow2.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your code so far is somewhat needed, but based purely on the image I would do the following:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img src="header.gif" />
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 10%; width: 10%; bottom: 0px;">Left text</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 30%; width: 10%; bottom: 0px;">Middle text</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; width: 10%; bottom: 0px;">Right text</div>
</div>
```

Obviously without any code and only an image to go by I cant really help much - but this should get you well on the way to achieving this. At least some extra effort could have been put into the image, such as what elements you are using where and so on. You would also need to put the above into CSS - but this is just a quick, untested attempt to achieve what you want.